# Elasticsearch msearch query with no hits

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elastic 5.1, (new to elastic in general) and I have a list which I send using msearch to elastic.

However the following does not return any hits, but my documents in the index look like:

```
{
"_index": "all_items",
"_type": "product",
"_id": "1000002007900",
"_version": 2,
"found": true,
"_source": {
    "doc": {
        "title": "title here",
        "brand": null,
        "updatedOn": "2016-12-22T14:00:26.016290",
        "price": 49,
        "viewed7": 0,
        "idInShop": "11",
        "active": true,
        "model": null,
        "_id": 1000002007900,
        "purchased7": 0
    },
    "doc_as_upsert": true
}
```

}

and here is the body sent to msearch

```
[
{
    "index": "all_items",
    "type": "product"
},
{
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": "desc"
        }
    ],
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "active": true
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "should": [],
                    "must_not": [],
                    "must": []
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "script_score": {
                        "script": {
                            "lang": "painless",
                            "inline": "_score * params.constant * (doc['discountPrice'] > 0 ? doc['price'] / doc['discountPrice'] : 0)",
                            "params": {
                                "constant": 1.2
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "score_mode": "multiply"
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 3
}
```

]

If I only send `{"query":{"match_all":{}}}` I get hits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`match query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) to get the result you want.

```
[
{
    "index": "all_items",
    "type": "product"
},
{
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": "desc"
        }
    ],
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "active": true
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "script_score": {
                        "script": {
                            "lang": "painless",
                            "inline": "_score * params.constant * (doc['discountPrice'] > 0 ? doc['price'] / doc['discountPrice'] : 0)",
                            "params": {
                                "constant": 1.2
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "score_mode": "multiply"
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 3
}
]
```

You can read more about `match query` and `term based query` (which you used) at this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/term-vs-full-text.html).